# Output an HTML from ASP Classic in a PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf, asp-classic

I need some ideas.

So I working in ASP Classic. The program must generate PDFs from a dynamic report. We  use FPDF in a ASP version. But is too complicated because the given library and version can't render PDF directly from the HTML, it must build line per line with the class tools.

My boss don't want to pay a cent for a commercial solution.

On the Internet there a lot of library that convert a HTML directly into PDF -FPDF included-. And we have both, ASP and PHP servers in two different domains and machines.

So what I think is:

1. Put a button on the ASP Machine. The button is an URL to a PHP file with a function, that I send it with a ton of variables in GET.
2. The PHP call back the ASP machine asking for the report (with the Gets vars)
3. I capture the output with ob_start's PHP function
4. I dump the buffer content into a X class of PHP that will convert the captured html into PDF.

My boss indicate me that between points 1 and 2 I send unnecessary variables, because the vars are already present in the ASP machine.

So, the question is: How I can avoid to go and back 3 times between the machines?

For example: 
 Send the html ready from the ASP to the PHP (without show an output to the user)

- Can't be a REST request,Web-service, etc.
- Must be transparent to the clients.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use javascript?  This is how we would get around the horrible classic asp limitations a few years ago.

Comment: even with javascript he will be passing vars to the PHP script.  Makes no difference if you are passing them from ASP to PHP or from  JS to PHP via AJAX, its still going to pass variables.   The only alternative if you are worried about passing variables is to either save everything to a job (db row or txt file) and then pass the job id and have the php script read all the variables form the DB again.   Passing vars would be still faster.  Its dirty, but it works.  

PS you can check out WebSuperGOO as a PDF component.  I think they have a free version for ASP

Comment: Also look into Adobe FDF active x library.  It too is free.  Probably hard to find now, but years ago I used to use it to form fill pdf forms using classic asp.

Comment: What about [ASPPDF](http://www.asppdf.com/)? I know your boss said he doesn't want to pay but from what I remember it's relatively inexpensive and comes with support. You can then make PDFs that are either fillable or not.